# How to set layouts instead of text in RadioButton

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button, android-radiobutton

Normally Radio Buttons, you can have text along with them, is there a possibility to add a layout instead of text as shown in figure below?

**P.S**:

I have kept all the radio buttons in a radio group. Just for this layout sake, i don't want to create a separate linear layout along the radio group.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer maybe overkill but you can create a custom view, i put together what you have with the following

**custom_radio_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:text="For one hour"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/radioButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/radioButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:text="Until 9:08pm"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/radioButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/radioButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:text="-"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**RadioCustomLayout.kt**

```
class RadioCustomLayout: ConstraintLayout {
    constructor(context: Context?): super(context)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?): super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int): super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    init {
        inflate(context, R.layout.custom_radio_view, this)
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.test.test.RadioCustomLayout
        android:id="@+id/group1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

With a few `declare-styleable` and callbacks you could create a fully re-usable layout, rather than a radio-group